# Linq with DbContext - item with two keys complicate scenario

Tags: c#, linq

I have this scenario:

```
public class A
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int Number{get;set;}
}

public class B 
{
   public A AInstance{get;set;} 
}
```

and I have this function:

```
 public List<B> GetBFromA(List<A> aList)
 {
      ...
      List<B> database_bInstances = db.GetBInstances();

      //here I want linq query that will filter to me the B instances from the database, according to the aList
 }
```

I hope the idea is clear. the scenario is that I get all the B instances from the database and filter all the B according to the list of A in the input. if for some B its A instance(identified by **Name and Number** exists in the input aList it will stay if not it will removef from the B list).

**Edit**: I am using entity framework DbContext! those it is not letting me to make:

```
database_bInstances.Where(b => aList.Any(a => (a.Name == b.AInstance.Name)
                                       && (a.Number == b.AInstance.Number)))
```

and it throws exception: Unable to create a constant value of type A. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Comment: You can implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `A` and simply use `Contains`. Btw. `GetBInstances` materializes `List<B>`, which means you'll get a lot of items from database into memory. Is that intentional?

Comment: WOW I don't thought about it, no in the real scenario I will to the linq on the db object like db.B.Where(...)

Comment: Then `Equals` won't work, because it wan't be translated into SQL query.

Comment: Ok very good point if I use the DbContext of entity framework you say that I can't override equals?

Comment: You can, but if you try using that `Equals` method within LINQ to Entities query it won't work. Eg if you try using `Contains<A>` you'll get exception saying only primitive types can be compared like that. But you can still use `Equals` in your *standard* C# code, when dealing with entities after they are retrieved from db.

Answer (score 1):

This expression will give you the desired `B`s.

```
database_bInstances.Where(b => aList.Any(a => (a.Name == b.AInstance.Name)
                                           && (a.Number == b.AInstance.Number)))
```

While this will work, it does not look to me like the best thing to do, but without more information I can not make a better suggestion.

If you have properly implemented `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or if you use an O/R mapper that ensures reference equality for objects representing the same database row you can just use `Contains` instead of `Any`.

```
database_bInstances.Where(b => aList.Contains(b.AInstance))
```

Answer (score 1):

If Equals works for A then this will work

```
 List<B> database_bInstances = db.GetBInstances();

 List<B> new_list = database_bInstances
              .Where(b => aList.Contains(b.AInstance));
```

If not then do this:

```
 List<B> database_bInstances = db.GetBInstances();

 List<B> new_list = database_bInstances
              .Where(b => aList.Any(a => b.AInstance.Name == a.Name && b.AInstance.Number == a.Number));
```

Comment: @ilayzeidman - Please edit to show the full function **AND** how you are calling that function.  It sounds like aList is declared differently than you show in your question to me, but I can't be sure.  Since Linq is lazy this is where it would show up if there was a problem with aList parameter.